# how to set string value from css class?

Tags: jquery

I have the following css

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

I want to set string "test" in variable like this:

```
var $stringvalue = $('.test').class(); /*but seems wrong statment*/
```

Comment: Please clarify. This is really unclear

Comment: var $stringvalue = "test" should be result

Comment: I call it programming with closed eyes.

Comment: Don't you notice there is `test` in `$('.test')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.attr()`](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fattr%2F&ei=_dQuUtWLCMSXtQaOtIGYDg&usg=AFQjCNE1qhpJI2G8J0vSJXrZ_Vf8dTKrTg&sig2=ZhCz8PtkHowVwylclLh_eQ&bvm=bv.51773540,d.Yms) function.

```
var $stringvalue = $('.test').attr("class");
```

- Notice this will return all the classes that were set in the `class attribute` on the original DOM.

---

You can also use the native `className` property to get an array of class names.

```
var classes = $('.test')[0].className.split(/\s+/)`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr()`

```
var $stringvalue = $('.test').attr('class');
```

`attr('class')` will get the class attribute of `div` with `class` of `test`.

Comment: @down voter...why.?? can you please explain..

Answer (score 0):

```
var $stringvalue = $('.test').class();
```

should be

```
var $stringvalue = $('.test').attr('class');
```